# Run code on powershell script termination to close files?

Tags: powershell, terminate

I've got a script that's chewing through a lot of objects, and sometimes I want to kill it in the middle of the run because I see something going south. Unfortunately, I'm writing to a log file using System.IO.StreamWriter, and whenever I send a Ctrl-C, my log files are stuck open.

Is there any way I can define some kind of handler or exiting function that allows me to gracefully close filehandles and connections that I have open?

Answer (score 4):

Might try using Try/Catch/Finally, putting your close() commands in the Finally block.

Comment: I'm doing that in several parts of the program for various things, but it's more like I need something like the equivalent of "trap control_c SIGINT" from Bash. Although I guess I could put the entire script in a giant try{} statement and throw a finally{}. Can you nest try statements? This just seems like the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, you can nest Try statements.

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell 2.0 and up, you can define a [`Trap`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) which will fire when a terminating error occurs. You can define multiple traps to capture different exceptions. This could result in much cleaner code than `try/catch` littered everywhere, or wrapping the entire script in one big `try/catch`.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't look like I can trap Ctrl-C (whatever that appears as, to the script itself). At least, I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a script, use `exit` .If an exception is thrown, use `try/catch/finally` with close() commands in `finally`. If it's just an if-test, try something like this:

```
function Close-Script {
    #If stream1 is created
    if($stream1) { 
        $stream1.Close()
    }

    #Terminate script
    exit
}

$stream1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter filename.txt


If(a test that detects your error) {
    Close-Script
}
```

If the amounts of streamwriters varies from time to time, you can collect them to an array and close them. Ex:

```
function Close-Script {
    #Close streams
    $writers | % { $_.Close() }

    #Terminate script
    exit
}

$writers = @()
$stream1 = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter filename.txt
$writers += $stream1
$stream2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter filename2.txt
$writers += $stream2

If(a test that detects your error) {
    Close-Script
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's less that there are actual errors that an If statement would catch. It's more like I'm watching debugging output and say, "oh, that's wrong, I've got to fix it", but I can't kill it until it's finished the loop of 150+ entities.

Comment: if you want a cleanup function after you use `ctrl+c`, you could use the function as I provided, but you would need to make the vars in the global scope(e.g. `$global:writers`), OR dot-source when running the script (`. .\myscript.ps1`), then calling `Close-Script` after `ctrl+c`